# Как добавить пустой массив в массив? - php

Tags: php

Есть массив:

```
$data = Array (
0 => Array ('id' => 1, 'check' => ''), 
1 => Array ('id' => 2, 'check' => ''), 
2 => Array ('id' => 3, 'check' => 'on'), 
3 => Array ('id' => 4, 'check' => ''), 
4 => Array ('id' => 5, 'check' => ''),
);
```

Нужно сделать что-бы если 'check'=='on', то добавлялся пустой массив после массива с 'check'=='on':

```
$data = Array (
0 => Array ('id' => 1, 'check' => ''), 
1 => Array ('id' => 2, 'check' => ''), 
2 => Array ('id' => 3, 'check' => 'on'),
3 => Array (),
4 => Array ('id' => 4, 'check' => ''), 
5 => Array ('id' => 5, 'check' => ''),
);
```

https://3v4l.org/GPQKc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = Array (
        0 => Array ('id' => 1, 'check' => ''),
        1 => Array ('id' => 2, 'check' => ''),
        2 => Array ('id' => 3, 'check' => 'on'),
        3 => Array ('id' => 4, 'check' => ''),
        4 => Array ('id' => 5, 'check' => 'on'),
        5 => Array ('id' => 5, 'check' => ''),
    );
function addEmptyArray(array $data): array
{
    $result = [];
    foreach($data as $position_arr){
        $result[] = $position_arr;
        if(!empty($position_arr['check'])){
            $result[] = [];
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
print_r(addEmptyArray($data));
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно как то так:

```
$data = Array (
        0 => Array ('id' => 1, 'check' => ''),
        1 => Array ('id' => 2, 'check' => ''),
        2 => Array ('id' => 3, 'check' => 'on'),
        3 => Array ('id' => 4, 'check' => ''),
        4 => Array ('id' => 5, 'check' => ''),
    );

foreach ($data as $key => $value){
    if($value['check'] == 'on'){
        array_splice($data, $key + 1, 0, [[]]);
    }
}
```

Comment: в таких случаях массив лучше с конца перебирать.

Comment: Я думаю тут без разницы, т.к. числовые ключи функция каждый раз переиндексирует.

Comment: @ДмитрийГорный Если больше 1-го 'on', то работает некорректно: https://3v4l.org/4s8Zl